# How can I read from stdin in a test with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, testing, input, stdin

I'd like to read from stdin as part of a test for my Java project, which uses Maven as its build tool.

My Java code is something like this (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```java
try (Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  stdin.nextLine();
}
```

I am running tests normally, i.e., `mvn test`. When I run that command in my terminal, none of the lines I enter are read by my code and the test hangs forever.

Comment: I am aware that reading from stdin during tests is highly abnormal and, in many cases, a terrible idea. I know that mocking or reading from static input sources (such as files) is a common approach for testing code that usually reads user input.


The goal here is not to test code that reads from stdin, but rather, to read from stdin as part of the testing logic itself. Specifically, I've written an integration test that pauses to read a line from stdin ("press enter to continue"), then immediately performs an operation that's easier to verify with human eyes than programmatically.

Comment: Can you give more of context why do you need to read stdin and what kind of problem you are testing?

Comment: You should consider finding a way to verify the output programmatically. You will be unable to run CI if you need a user to verify something.

Comment: If you really need user input, maybe consider using a CI tool that waits for an external action. Then the CI continues from there.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm testing the latency for adjusting my Philips Hue lights. User presses enter during the test, test immediately uses my Java client to change light color, user observes latency between keystroke and light color changing.

Comment: @DavidV The "output" being examined is the latency for changing the color of some Philips Hue lights using my Java client. If you have suggestions on verifying this programmatically, please feel free to provide them. I should also note that this is for a small personal project that has no CI and for which tests are all run manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by configuring the `maven-surefire-plugin` (or, for integration tests, the `maven-failsafe-plugin`) with `forkCount` set to `0`.

However, like @cyberbrain mentions, this will disable parallel test execution.

It's usually bad practice to read from stdin (or use any kind of non-deterministic input) during tests. If possible, consider using mocking or static input during tests instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Maven Surefire plugin forks additional JVM(s) to run the actual tests, and your inputs are not sent over to that JVM. If the inputs were sent to the testing JVMs, parallel testing would not be possible anylonger.

Probably an update of the code you want to unit test is easier than any configuration of the maven testing infrastructure to support stdin.

Also please note that "user input" like reading from stdin qualifies a test as an integration test (as it combines two parts of a system).

If you want to test this, split it into an automatic part (a real unit test that works without reading stdin) and a manual test where you run your software, enter data according to a test protocol and also note down if the result is meeting the also documented expectations for that given input.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the info I needed to accomplish what I wanted. By configuring the `maven-surefire-plugin` with `<forkCount>0</forkCount>`, I was able to read from stdin during my test.

You're correct that this is more of an integration test than a unit test, but the same applies with the `maven-failsafe-plugin`.

If you'd like to edit your answer to include this solution, please do so (and feel free to keep in the usual warnings about this being bad practice and inadvisable in most cases). Otherwise, I'll post and accept my own answer with this approach (with its own warnings).